# There are table that appears after clicking on the icon. I need to parse the level of the CO

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

There are divs like that:

```html
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-green awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(79px, 254px, 0px); z-index: 254; outline: none;"><i style="" class=" ion ion-ios-close  icon-black"></i></div>
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-red awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(144px, 276px, 0px); z-index: 276; outline: none;"><i style="" class=" ion ion-ios-close  icon-black"></i></div>
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-red awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(146px, 268px, 0px); z-index: 268;"><i style="" class=" ion ion-ios-close  icon-black"></i></div>
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-beige awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(14px, 218px, 0px); z-index: 218;"><i style="" class=" ion ion-ios-close  icon-black"></i></div>
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-green awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(29px, 212px, 0px); z-index: 212;"><i style="" class=" ion ion-ios-close  icon-black"></i></div>
```

and so on. After clicking one of them appears a table:

```html
<div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"><div class="leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(145px, 244px, 0px); bottom: -7px; left: -171px;"><div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper"><div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 301px;">
 2024-03-21 20:00:00<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="table_2933" border="1">
<caption><b><span style="color:#000000">ПНЗ№4 : Кустанай, ул. Маяковского-Волынова </span></b></caption><tbody><tr>
</tr></tbody><caption id="footer" align="bottom"><b><span style="color:#000000">Модель SILAM, адаптированная для Казахстана по ссылке:</span></b> <a href="http://silam.fmi.fi/roux/KAZ/">http://silam.fmi.fi/roux/KAZ/</a></caption>
<colgroup><col width="100">
<col width="100">
<col width="100">
<col width="100">
</colgroup><thead>
<tr>
  <th colspan="1" id="tableHTML_second_header_1" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;font-size:12px;text-align:center;"></th>
  <th colspan="4" id="tableHTML_second_header_2" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;font-size:12px;text-align:center;">Концентрация, мкг/м3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th id="tableHTML_header_1" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align:center;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Показатели</th>
  <th id="tableHTML_header_2" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align:center;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Фактическое значение</th>
  <th id="tableHTML_header_3" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align:center;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Прогноз 24 часа</th>
  <th id="tableHTML_header_4" style="height:30px;background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align:center;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Прогноз 48 часов</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_1" style="text-align:center;">CO</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_2" style="text-align:center;">462</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_3" style="text-align:center;">264</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_4" style="text-align:center;">268</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_1" style="text-align:center;">NO</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_2" style="text-align:center;">45</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_3" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_4" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_1" style="text-align:center;">NO2</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_2" style="text-align:center;"><span style="background-color:#ff0000">485</span></td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_3" style="text-align:center;">4</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_4" style="text-align:center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_1" style="text-align:center;">SO2</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_2" style="text-align:center;">6</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_3" style="text-align:center;">6</td>
  <td id="tableHTML_column_4" style="text-align:center;">3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div></div><div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container"><div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div></div><a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="#close">×</a></div></div>
```

I need to parse the CO, NO, NO2, and SO2 levels. The problem is that everything is gone after exiting the table and there is no stable element that I can use. http://ecodata.kz:3838/app_dem_visual/ to know better

I have tried that, I think that is the best I have:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://ecodata.kz:3838/app_dem_visual/');

    await page.waitForSelector('.ico');

    const icons = await page.$$eval('.ico', icons => icons.map(icon => icon.outerHTML));

    
    const popups = [];
    for (const icon of icons) {
      
      await page.setContent(icon);
      
      try {
        await page.waitForSelector('.leaflet-popup-content', { timeout: 10000 });

        const popupText = await page.$eval('.leaflet-popup-content', popup => popup.textContent);
        popups.push(popupText);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while waiting for popup:', error);
      } 
    }

    console.log(popups);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during script execution:', error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I've tried accessing the link you provided (directly, via proxies etc), and it times out in every case. It's rather difficult to help, without resorting to guesses. That being said, some general advice - try to do this manually, at first. Open the webpage, and inspect the elements which render. Watch the DOM for changes once you click on a marker, and a popup shows up. That should give you the general idea of what to watch with Puppeteer.